# Oracle Function Based Indexes and CASE Statement

Tags: oracle, function, indexing

I have a table with three mutually exclusive columns.

```
create table key_tab
(
  a_key number null,
  b_key number null,
  c_key number null,
  key_tab_key number not null <-- Primary Key
)
/
```

Example: when A_KEY is populated, both B_KEY and C_KEY are null.

I have a SELECT statement as follows :

```
select CASE INP_KEY 
    WHEN 'A' THEN 
       select A_KEY from KEY_TAB where A_KEY=:2 AND KEY_TAB_KEY =:3 
    WHEN 'B' THEN 
       select B_KEY from KEY_TAB where B_KEY=:2 and KEY_TAB_KEY = :3
    WHEN 'C' then
       select C_KEY from KEY_TAB where C_KEY=:2 and KEY_TAB_KEY = :3
END FROM dual
```

I have created a function based index as follows :

```
unique index key_tab_ix on key_tab
( case when a_key is not null then a_key
       when b_key is not null then b_key
       when c_key is not null then c_key
  end,
  key_tab_key
```

I have a process which reads a staging table and then queries KEY_TAB. If a record is not found then it inserts the record into KEY_TAB.

The process runs very fast for first few 100 records and then drastically slows down. It could be because that initially there are very records to search but as the table grows - it has more records to search. And the index does not seems to be helping.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If `key_tab_key` is the primary key supported by a unique index, I would expect that that would be much more selective than any index on a_key, b_key or c_key. I would check the query plan to see if it's using that unique index, and if not, why not.

Answer (score 2):

If it's guaranteed that only one of a_key, b_key, and c_key will not be null, (with for example a check constraint) then you could create your unique index as:

```
create unique index key_tab_ix on key_tab (coalesce(a_key,b_key,c_key));
```

I would change your select statement to the following:

```
select A_KEY from KEY_TAB where A_KEY=:2 AND KEY_TAB_KEY = :3 and INP_KEY = 'A'
union all
select B_KEY from KEY_TAB where B_KEY=:2 and KEY_TAB_KEY = :3 and INP_KEY = 'B'
union all
select C_KEY from KEY_TAB where C_KEY=:2 and KEY_TAB_KEY = :3 and INP_KEY = 'C'
```

or you might even be able drop the `and INP_KEY = '?'` predicates and simplify it even further as:

```
select coalesce(a_key,b_key,c_key)
  from KEY_TAB
 where coalesce(a_key,b_key,c_key) = :2
   and KEY_TAB_KEY = :3
```

Especially since you'll have created an index on `coalesce(a_key,b_key,c_key)` above.